Calculating negative values with numpy.log
I'm trying to do a calculation that contains negative values inside a log (base-e) function.  Python's numpy package has the log function, MWE below:
from numpy import exp, log
z = 1j*log(-1.1)
print(exp(-1j*z))

but it gives an error message:
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  z = 1j*log(-1.1)

The correct answer is -1.1 which we can be easily verified on WolframAlpha.  Is there an alternative numpy log function that can handle negative values?  If not, is there a simple workaround or formula that I can use?

As far as I'm aware, the real version of log is only defined for (0, inf). To use the complex version, you need to pass in a complex number:
z = log(-1.1 + 0j)

On more careful reading, docs confirm:

For real-valued input data types, log always returns real output. For each value that cannot be expressed as a real number or infinity, it yields nan and sets the invalid floating point error flag.


Assuming you're working with numpy arrays (if you're only using scalars then you can use cmath per this answer), you can either manually convert the input to complex (see this answer and this answer) or use numpy's emath for automatic domain handling. In this case, use np.emath.log.
import numpy as np

z = 1j*np.emath.log(-1.1)
print(np.exp(-1j*z))

You may wish to wrap your final output with np.real_if_close. I got -1.1 with a very small (approximately machine 0) imaginary component.

On using emath you do not need to multiply by 1j ie z =np.emath.log(-1.1) is sufficient.

@Onyambu I agree that the 1j outside the log and the -1j inside the exp is redundant, but I assumed OP had some other reason for doing it that way. Maybe z is used elsewhere in the code? Either way, I chose to keep the code as similar as possible to what OP showed.

You might also be interested in using the functions from Python’s built-in cmath library:
import cmath
print(cmath.log(-1.1))


Another possible solution, which defines x with dtype=np.complex128:
x = np.array(-1.1, dtype=np.complex128)
z = 1j * np.log(x)
result = np.exp(-1j * z)
print(result)

Output:
(-1.1+1.3471114790620887e-16j)


You have to process the logarithm in the complex domain (i.e., x = -1.1 should be treated as x = -1.1 + 1j*0), which could be done in multiple ways, e.g.,
np.log(abs(x)) + 1j*np.arctan2(np.imag(x), np.real(x))
# (0.09531017980432493+3.141592653589793j)

or
np.log(np.complex128(x))
# (0.09531017980432493+3.141592653589793j)

